# Database records not updating?

Tags: php, mysql

I've got a database right, I've displayed a table on a page (Login.php) and have the necessary `Edit` Link's on each database record  ->

```
echo "<td><a href='../DAL/edit_consultant.php?ID=$arrRows[Consultant_Id]'>Edit</a>";
```

I cannot find the reason why the records won't get updated?! E.g When I click the `submit new details` button. It will refresh the page and then display the the input fields that are empty.

If someone could have a look at the code, that'd be great. I've had trouble with this for a while now.

**What is working**:

- The columns from the database are put into the `edit_consultant.php` form, depending on the Consultant_Id passed in the edit `href=''`

**What isn't working**:

- When I click "submit new details" It won't update the database table. It will instead do nothing

db_functions.php:

```
  <?php
    ini_set("display_errors", 1);
    ini_set("display_startup_errors", 1);
    error_reporting(-1);
    //Database connection Variables
    $localhost = "localhost";
    $user = "root";
    $password = "root";
    $db = "Dalton";
    $dsn = "mysql:host=$localhost;dbname=$db";

    //Declare Global Variables
    $dbConnection = NULL;
    $stmt = NULL;
    $numRecords = NULL;

    //This connect database function can be used to connect anywhere
    function connect(){

    //These are variables from the other file (dblibary) - global allows access to these variables
        global $user, $password, $dsn, $dbConnection; //Required to access the global variables.

        try{
            $dbConnection = new PDO($dsn, $user, $password); 
            $dbConnection->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
        }
        catch(PDOException $error){
            //display error message if connection doesnt work
             echo "The following error occured: " . $error->getMessage();
        }
    }

    function insertContact(){
    global $dbConnection, $stmt, $strName, $strEmail, $strPhone, $strTitle, $strGender, $booOk;
    // global $booname, $booemail, $boophone, $bootitle,$boogender, $booOk;
    connect();

        $sqlStr = "INSERT INTO D_customer values('".$strName."','".$strEmail."','".$strPhone."','".$strTitle."','".$strGender."');";

        try{
            $stmt = $dbConnection->exec($sqlStr);
        }
        catch(PDOException $error){
            $errinfo = ($dbConnection->errorInfo());
            if($errinfo[1] == 1062){
                echo "This Customer ID already Exists!";   
            }
            else{
                echo "An Error occured: " . $error->getMessage();   
            }
            $booOk = 0;
        }

        //Close the DB connection
        $dbConnection = NULL;
    }

    /*INSERT INTO DATABASE FUNCTION (CONTACT FORM)-------------------------*/
    function updateContact(){
        global $dbConnection, $stmt, $booOk;
        global $booname, $booemail, $boophone, $bootitle,$boogender, $booOk;
        global $strName, $strEmail, $strNumber, $strQuery, $strGender;
        connect();

        $sqlStr = "INSERT INTO D_contact values('".$strName."','".$strEmail."','".$strNumber."','".$strTitle."','".$strGender."');";

        try{
            $stmt = $dbConnection->exec($sqlStr);
        }
        catch(PDOException $error){
            $errinfo = ($dbConnection->errorInfo());
            if($errinfo[1] == 1062){
                echo "This Customer ID already Exists!";   
            }
            else{
                echo "An Error occured: " . $error->getMessage();   
            }
            $booOk = 0;
        }

        //Close the DB connection
        $dbConnection = NULL;
    }

    /*INSERT INTO DATABASE FUNCTION (CONTACT FORM)-------------------------*/

    /*READ THE DATABASE-------------------------------------------*/
    function readQuery($table){
            global $numRecords, $dbConnection, $stmt;
            connect();

            $sqlStr = "SELECT * FROM " . $table.";";
            // $sqlStr = 'SELECT  First_Name, Last_Name,Email FROM ' . $table . '";"';
            // $sqlStr = "SELECT 'First_Name', 'Last_Name', 'Email' FROM " . $table .";";

            try{
                $stmt = $dbConnection->query($sqlStr);

                if($stmt === false){
                    die("Error executing the qquery: $sqlStr");   
                }
            }
            catch(PDOException $error){
                echo "An Error occured: " . $error->getMessage();   
            }
            $numRecords = $stmt->rowCount();

            //Close the DB connection
            $dbConnection = NULL;
     }
     /*READ THE DATABASE-------------------------------------------*/

    function readQuerySingle($table, $column, $colValue, $colType)
    {
        global $numRecords, $dbConnection, $stmt;

        connect(); //Run connect function

        $sqlStr = NULL;  //Initialise Variable to hold query

        if($colType === "numeric")
        {
            //Select Individual Record
            $sqlStr = "SELECT * FROM ".$table." WHERE ".$column." = ".$colValue.";";
        }
        else   //If Data-Type is non numeric
        {
            //Select Individual Record
            $sqlStr = "SELECT * FROM ".$table." WHERE ".$column." = '".$colValue."';";
        }

        //Run Query
        try
        {
            $stmt = $dbConnection->query($sqlStr);
            if($stmt === false)
            {
                die("Error executing the query: $sqlStr");
            }
        }
        catch(PDOException $error)
        {
            //Display error message if applicable
            echo "An Error occured: ".$error->getMessage();
        }

        //How many records are there?
        $numRecords = $stmt->rowcount();

        //Close the database connection
        $dbConnection = NULL;
    }

    function updateConsultant(){
    global $dbConnection, $stmt, $booOk;

    global $strConsultant_Id, $strFirst_Name, $strLast_Name, $strHome_Phone;
    global $strMobile, $strEmail, $strDate_Commenced, $strDOB ,$strStreet_Address ;
    global $strSuburb, $strPost_Code;

    connect();

    // $sqlStr = "INSERT INTO D_Consultant values('".$strConsultant_Id."','".$strFirst_Name."','".$strLast_Name."','".$strHome_Phone."','".$strMobile."','".$strEmail."','".$strDate_Commenced."','".$strDOB."','".$strStreet_Address."','".$strSuburb."','".$strPost_Code."');";
    $sqlStr = "UPDATE D_Consultant SET ";
    $sqlStr .= "Consultant_Id = '".$strConsultant_Id."',";
    $sqlStr .= "First_Name = '".$strFirst_Name."',";
    $sqlStr .= "Last_Name = '".$strLast_Name."',";
    $sqlStr .= "Home_Phone = '".$strHome_Phone."',";
    $sqlStr .= "Mobile = '".$strMobile."',";
    $sqlStr .= "Email = '".$strEmail."',";
    $sqlStr .= "Date_Commenced = '".$strDate_Commenced."',";
    $sqlStr .= "DOB = '".$strDOB."',";
    $sqlStr .= "Street_Address = '".$strStreet_Address."',";
    $sqlStr .= "Suburb = '".$strSuburb."',";
    $sqlStr .= "Post_Code = '".$strPost_Code."' ";
    $sqlStr .= "WHERE Consultant_Id = '" . $strConsultant_Id ."';";

        try{
            $stmt = $dbConnection->exec($sqlStr);

        }
        catch(PDOException $error){
            $errinfo = ($dbConnection->errorInfo());
            if($errinfo[1] == 1062){
                echo "This Consultant ID already Exists!";   
            }
            else{
                echo "An Error occured: " . $error->getMessage();   
            }
            $booOk = 0;
        }

        //Close the DB connection
        $dbConnection = NULL;
    }

    function insertConsultant(){
    global $dbConnection, $stmt, $booOk;


    global $strConsultant_Id, $strFirst_Name, $strLast_Name, $strHome_Phone;
    global $strMobile, $strEmail, $strDate_Commenced, $strDOB, $strStreet_Address;
    global $strSuburb, $strPost_Code, $boo0k;

    connect();

    $sqlStr = "INSERT INTO D_Consultant values('".$strConsultant_Id."','".$strFirst_Name."','".$strLast_Name."','".$strHome_Phone."','".$strMobile."','".$strEmail."','".$strDate_Commenced."','".$strDOB."','".$strStreet_Address."','".$strSuburb."','".$strPost_Code."');";

        try{
            $stmt = $dbConnection->exec($sqlStr);
        }                
        catch(PDOException $error){
            $errinfo = ($dbConnection->errorInfo());
            if($errinfo[1] == 1062){
                echo "This Consultant ID already Exists!";   
            }
            else{
                echo "An Error occured: " . $error->getMessage();   
            }
            $booOk = 0;
        }

        //Close the DB connection
        $dbConnection = NULL;
    }
?>
```

edit_consultant.php:

```
    <?php
        include "../PHP/head.php";
        ini_set("display_errors", 1);
        ini_set("display_startup_errors", 1);
        error_reporting(-1);

        require_once("db_functions.php");
      require_once("../BLL/validate_form.php");

    // $strConsultant_Id = $strFirst_Name = $strLast_Name = $strHome_Phone = "";
    // $strMobile = $strEmail = $strDate_Commenced = $strDOB = $strStreet_Address = "";
    // $strSuburb = $strPost_Code = "";

    $booDate_Commenced = $booConsultant_Id = $booLast_Name = $booHome_Phone = $booMobile = 0;
    $booEmail = $booDOB = $booStreet_Address = $booFirst_Name = $booSuburb = $booPost_code = 0;


    $booOk = 1;

        echo "<br />";
        echo "<br /><br /><br />";
        if(isset($_POST["submit"])){
          updateConsultant();
        }
        else{
            if(isset($_GET["ID"])) $strConsultant_Id = $_GET["ID"];
            readQuerySingle("D_Consultant", "Consultant_Id", $strConsultant_Id, "NonNumeric");

            //If there is a record continue
            if($numRecords == 0){
                echo "<span class='error'>No Matching Branch Found!</span><br /><br />";

            } 
            else{
                $arrRows = NULL;

                //Get first and only result from database

                $arrRows = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

                $strConsultant_Id = $arrRows['Consultant_Id'];
                $strFirst_Name = $arrRows['First_Name'];
                $strLast_Name = $arrRows['Last_Name'];
                $strHome_Phone = $arrRows['Home_Phone'];
                $strMobile = $arrRows['Mobile'];
                $strEmail = $arrRows['Email'];
                $strDate_Commenced = $arrRows['Date_Commenced'];
                $strDOB = $arrRows['DOB'];
                $strStreet_Address = $arrRows['Street_Address'];
            $strSuburb = $arrRows['Suburb'];
            $strPost_Code = $arrRows['Post_Code'];


            }
        }

           echo "<form action='edit_consultant.php' method='post'><table id='mavis'>";
           echo "<tr><th>Consultant Id</th><td><input type='text' name='strConsultant_Id' size='20' value='".$strConsultant_Id."' /></td>";
           if($booConsultant_Id) echo "<td>Please enter a Consultant Id</td>";

           echo "<tr><th>First Name</th><td><input type='text' name='strFirst_Name' size='20' value='".$strFirst_Name."' /></td>";
           if($booFirst_Name) echo "<td>Please Enter your First Name</td>";

           echo "<tr><th>Last Name</th><td><input type='text' name='strLast_Name' size='20' value='".$strLast_Name."' /></td>";
           if($booLast_Name) echo "<td>Please enter a Last Name</td>";

           echo "<tr><th>Home Phone</th><td><input type='text' name='strHome_Phone' size='20' value='".$strHome_Phone."' /></td>";
           if($booHome_Phone) echo "<td>Please enter a Home Phone</td>";

           echo "<tr><th>Mobile Number</th><td><input type='text' name='strMobile' size='20' value='".$strMobile."' /></td>";
           if($booMobile) echo "<td>Please enter a Mobile Number</td>";

           echo "<tr><th>Email</th><td><input type='text' name='strEmail' size='20' value='".$strEmail."' /></td>";
           if($booEmail) echo "<td>Please enter an Email!</td>";

           echo "<tr><th>Date Commenced</th><td><input type='text' name='strDate_Commenced' size='20' value='".$strDate_Commenced."' /></td>";
           if($booDate_Commenced) echo "<td>Please enter a Date Commenced!</td>";

           echo "<tr><th>DOB</th><td><input type='text' name='strDOB' size='20' value='".$strDOB."' /></td>";
           if($booDOB) echo "<td>Please enter a DOB Number!</td>";

           echo "<tr><th>Street_Address</th><td><input type='text' name='strStreet_Address' size='20' value='".$strStreet_Address."' /></td>";
           if($booStreet_Address) echo "<td>Please enter a  Street_Address!</td>";

           echo "<tr><th>Street_Address</th><td><input type='text' name='strSuburb' size='20' value='".$strSuburb."' /></td>";
           if($booSuburb) echo "<td>Please enter a Suburb!</td>";

           echo "<tr><th>Post Code</th><td><input type='text' name='strPost_Code' size='20' value='".$strPost_Code."' /></td>";
           if($booPost_code) echo "<td>Please enter a Post Code !</td>";


           echo "<tr><td></td><td><input type='submit' name='submit' value='Submit New Details' /></td></tr></table></form>";


      include "../PHP/footer.php";  
    ?>
```

login.php:

```
    <?php include "head.php"; ?>

    <body>
    <div id="particles-js"> 
        <div class='open-text'>
            <div class='open-text-wrap login-wrap'>

            <form method='post'>
                <input type='text' placeholder="Login Code" name='strCode' />
                <input type='submit' name='submit' value='Login' />
            </form>
            <?php 
                $display = false;
                function checkCode()
                {

                }
                    if(isset($_POST["submit"])){
                        if($_POST["strCode"] === "admin"){
                            $display = true;

                        }
                        else{
                            echo "<div class='error-login'>Authentication Failed</div>";
                        }
                    }
                ?>

            </div>
        </div> 
    </div>


    <main>
    <div class='container section-one-position cont-colour'>
        <hr />
        <div class='section-one'>
        <h1>Consultant List</h1>
        </div>
        <hr />
    </div>

    <br />
    <div class='full-container'>
    <!-- DISPLAY THE TABLE FROM DATABASE -->
     <?php
        ini_set("display_errors", 1);
        ini_set("display_startup_errors", 1);
        error_reporting(-1);
        require_once("../DAL/db_functions.php");


    if($display == true)
    {
        //Run query on branch table
        readQuery("D_Consultant");


    //If there are any details in branch table continue

        if($numRecords === 0){
            echo "<p>No Branches Found!</p>";
        }   
        else{
            $arrRows = NULL;

            //Create table and headings
            echo "<table id='dalton' border='0'>";
            echo "<tr>";
            // echo "<th>Prospect_No</th>";
            echo "<th>Consultant ID</th>";
            echo "<th>Surname</th>";
            echo "<th>First Name</th>";
            echo "<th>Home Phone</th>";
            echo "<th>Mobile</th>";
            // echo "<th>Phone</th>";
            echo "<th>Email</th>";
            echo "<th>Date Commenced</th>";
            echo "<th>DOB</th>";
            echo "<th>Street Address</th>";
            echo "<th>Suburb</th>";
            echo "<th>Post code</th>";
            echo "<th></th>";


            //echo "<th>Email</th>";

            echo "</tr>";

            while($arrRows = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
                echo "<tr>";
                // echo "<td>".$arrRows['Consultant_Id']."</td>";
                echo "<td>".$arrRows['Consultant_Id']."</td>";
                echo "<td>".$arrRows['Last_Name']."</td>";
                echo "<td>".$arrRows['First_Name']."</td>";
                echo "<td>".$arrRows['Home_Phone']."</td>";
                echo "<td>".$arrRows['Mobile']."</td>";
                // echo "<td>".$arrRows['Home_Phone']."</td>";
                echo "<td>".$arrRows['Email']."</td>";
                echo "<td>".$arrRows['Date_Commenced']."</td>";
                echo "<td>".$arrRows['DOB']."</td>";
                echo "<td>".$arrRows['Street_Address']."</td>";
                echo "<td>".$arrRows['Suburb']."</td>";
                echo "<td>".$arrRows['Post_Code']."</td>";



                echo "<td><a href='../DAL/edit_consultant.php?ID=$arrRows[Consultant_Id]'>Edit</a>";
                echo "<br /><a href='../DAL/delete_confirm.php?TYPE=Consultant&amp;ID=$arrRows[Consultant_Id]'>Delete</a></td></tr>";

            }
            echo "</table>";

        }
    }
    else{
       echo "<p>Please enter your login code to view our list of consultants</p>"; 
    }

    ?>
    </div>
    <br />
    <div class='container section-one-position cont-colour'>
            <?php echo "<form action='../DAL/add_branch.php' method='post'>";
            echo "<input type='submit' value='Add a consultant' />";
            echo "</form>";

            echo "<p></P><P>$numRecords Records Returned</P>";?>
    </div>

    <!-- CONSULTANT LIST ABOVE _________________________________ -->

    <div class='container section-one-position cont-colour'>
        <hr />
        <div class='section-one'>
        <h1>Projects List</h1>
        </div>
        <hr />
    </div>

    <br />
    <div class='full-container'>
    <!-- DISPLAY THE TABLE FROM DATABASE -->
     <?php
        ini_set("display_errors", 1);
        ini_set("display_startup_errors", 1);
        error_reporting(-1);
        require_once("../DAL/db_functions.php");


    if($display == true)
    {
        //Run query on branch table
        readQuery("D_Project");
        //readQuery("D_Projects");


    //If there are any details in branch table continue

        if($numRecords === 0){
            echo "<p>No Branches Found!</p>";
        }   
        else{
            $arrRows = NULL;

            //Create table and headings
            echo "<table id='dalton' border='0'>";
            echo "<tr>";
            // echo "<th>Prospect_No</th>";
            echo "<th>Project_No</th>";
            echo "<th>Project_Name</th>";
            echo "<th>Project_Description</th>";
            echo "<th>Project_Manager</th>";
            echo "<th>Start_Date</th>";
            // echo "<th>Phone</th>";
            echo "<th>Finish_Date</th>";
            echo "<th>Budget</th>";
            echo "<th>Cost_To_Date</th>";
            echo "<th>Tracking_Statement</th>";
            echo "<th>Client_No</th>";
            echo "<th></th>";


            //echo "<th>Email</th>";

            echo "</tr>";

            while($arrRows = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
                echo "<tr>";
                // echo "<td>".$arrRows['Consultant_Id']."</td>";
                echo "<td>".$arrRows['Project_No']."</td>";
                echo "<td>".$arrRows['Project_Name']."</td>";
                echo "<td>".$arrRows['Project_Description']."</td>";
                echo "<td>".$arrRows['Project_Manager']."</td>";
                echo "<td>".$arrRows['Start_Date']."</td>";
                // echo "<td>".$arrRows['Home_Phone']."</td>";
                echo "<td>".$arrRows['Finish_Date']."</td>";
                echo "<td>".$arrRows['Budget']."</td>";
                echo "<td>".$arrRows['Cost_To_Date']."</td>";
                echo "<td>".$arrRows['Tracking_Statement']."</td>";
                echo "<td>".$arrRows['Client_No']."</td>";



                echo "<td><a href='../DAL/edit_Project.php?ID=$arrRows[Project_No]'>Edit</a>";
                echo "<br /><a href='../DAL/delete_confirm.php?TYPE=Consultant&amp;ID=$arrRows[Project_No]'>Delete</a></td></tr>";

            }
            echo "</table>";

        }
    }
    else{
       echo "<p>Please enter your login code to view our list of consultants</p>"; 
    }

    ?>
    <br />
    </div>
    <div class='container section-one-position cont-colour'>
            <?php echo "<form action='../DAL/add_branch.php' method='post'>";
            echo "<input type='submit' value='Add a consultant' />";
            echo "</form>";

            echo "<p></P><P>$numRecords Records Returned</P>";?>
    </div>

    </main>
    <?php include "footer.php"; ?>
```

Comment: These all codes needed to solve the issue?

Comment: Not here but it's in a one drive folder - https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=f88647b499fea226!688&authkey=!AL1wecxeEBKgQ9Y&ithint=folder%2cDS_Store - If you want to have a better look :)

Comment: Ugh... lots of problems even without looking at the rest of the code... 1) Why are you setting string variables to integer 0 as a way of "blanking" them? 2) `if($booConsultant_Id) echo "<td>Please enter a Consultant Id</td>";` - if booConsultant_Id is true then echo an error? Your logic is wrong (or we've misunderstood something?) 3) What is your function `updateConsultant();` and where are the arguments for it [to be useful]? 4) Why does your `login.php` have more than login-related content? - It seems you haven't thought through the structure of the site...

Comment: 5) code vulnerable to sql injection